# Generate a local HTML file with PUG (npm / gulp)

Tags: javascript, html, npm, gulp, pug

How to create a HTML file with the same name as my pug file each time I save using gulp?

All the docs on https://pugjs.org/ explain how to return pug in console...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need task runner or module bundler for that. So choose one -grunt/gulp/webpack. Consider webpack as newest one and width best functionality.

Here an example width **gulp** as moust easy to understand from my point of view.

First install `npm` packages for compiling pug and watch for changes - `npm install --save gulp-pug gulp-watch`.

Then create and config your *gulpfile.js*.

First import an `npm` modules

```
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
```

Then create compiling task

```
gulp.task('pug',function() {
 return gulp.src('PATH_TO_TEMPLATES/*.jade')
 .pipe(pug({
    doctype: 'html',
    pretty: false
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/main/webapp/'));
});
```

And then create watcher

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
 return watch('PATH_TO_TEMPLATES/*.jade', { ignoreInitial: false })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('pug'));
 });
```

And run `gulp-watch` from you console.

Answer (score 6):

Here an example width gulp 4.0

install `npm` packages for compiling pug/jade by following command

`npm install --save gulp-pug` .

create script with name `gulpfile.js`

```
    //gulpfile.js
    var gulp = require("gulp"), pug = require('gulp-pug');

    function pugToHtml(){
       return gulp.src('src')
      .pipe(pug({
         pretty: true
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
    }
    exports.pugToHtml = pugToHtml;
```

We can run the above code using the following command in your file directory:

```
gulp pugToHtml
```

Answer (score 3):

You can now do the same without requiring `gulp-watch` as well.

Require module:

```
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
```

Task example:

```
//create task
gulp.task('pug', function buildHTML(){
 gulp.src('src/pre/*.pug')
 .pipe(pug())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('src/post'));
});
```

Watch:

```
//pug serve
gulp.task('watch', ['pug'], function() {
gulp.watch(['src/pug-pre/*.pug'], ['pug']);
});
```

You can then run `gulp watch`. You can also set `watch` to the default task so you only have to write `gulp` in Terminal, if you are not automating anything else:

```
// default task
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```